# Adding iOS support to an existing Titanium App

Tags: android, ios, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

I have a titanium mobile project and I had just selected "Android" in the deployment target at the time of creating it.

I would now like to add iOS target as well. Is it possible to add it to an existing project or will I have to create a new one?

Thanks!

Comment: Dont' really think that question belongs to SO, since here're only programming related stuff

Comment: How is this question off topic? Per the FAQ, this question is in regards to "software tools commonly used by programmers" and in determining how to configure a development project and switch from "Android Only" to "Android and iOS".

Comment: If you open your tiapp.xml in Titanium Studio, you will see checkboxes for each of the deployment targets that are available. iOS will be one of them, if you are on a Mac and have XCode installed. You can read more here: http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Getting+Started+with+Titanium#GettingStartedwithTitanium-PreparingforiOSdevelopment